# How do I resize a polygon?

Tags: java, javafx

My assignment is to make a smiley face that, when the windows resizes, fits in the borders. I can get all the other shapes to do that, but when I try with a polygon, I don't know how to do this. So if I could have help on how to resize a polygon from the javafx.node.shape.Shape package, that'd be great.

As always thanks for your timely help and I'm very sorry if I have violated many rules.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
    import javafx.scene.shape.*;

    public class smiley extends Application{
      @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        // Create a circle and set its properties
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2)); 
        circle.setRadius(50);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setFill(null);

        Polygon nose = new Polygon();
        nose.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{ 100.0, 90.0, 90.0, 120.0, 110.0, 120.0 });
        nose.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        nose.setFill(null);

        Ellipse leftEye = new Ellipse();
        leftEye.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2).add(20));
        leftEye.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2).subtract(20));
        leftEye.setRadiusX(15.0f);
        leftEye.setRadiusY(10.0f);
        leftEye.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        leftEye.setFill(null);

        Ellipse rightEye = new Ellipse();
        rightEye.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(20));
        rightEye.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2).subtract(20));
        rightEye.setRadiusX(15.0f);
        rightEye.setRadiusY(10.0f);
        rightEye.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rightEye.setFill(null);

        Circle leftPupil = new Circle();
        leftPupil.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2).add(20));
        leftPupil.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2).subtract(20));
        leftPupil.setRadius(7);
        leftPupil.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        Circle rightPupil = new Circle();
        rightPupil.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(20));
        rightPupil.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2).subtract(20));
        rightPupil.setRadius(7);
        rightPupil.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        Arc smile = new Arc();
        smile.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        smile.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2).add(20));
        smile.setRadiusX(25.0f);
        smile.setRadiusY(10.0f);
        smile.setStartAngle(180.0f);
        smile.setLength(180.0f);
        smile.setType(ArcType.OPEN);
        smile.setFill(null);
        smile.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        pane.getChildren().add(circle);
        pane.getChildren().add(nose);
        pane.getChildren().add(leftEye);
        pane.getChildren().add(rightEye);
        pane.getChildren().add(leftPupil);
        pane.getChildren().add(rightPupil);
        pane.getChildren().add(smile);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Assignment 14"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage


      }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you show scales if I'm not mistaken. You centered everything but use fixed offsets and sizes. You can do the same with the coordinates in the polygon. Simply do a bit of math and express those numbers relative to the center. But is that what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you're not talking about the smiley face growing/shrinking with the stage, but rather staying in the center of the stage as the stage resizes. All of your smiley face pieces do this except your polygon nose. The reason the nose doesn't do this is that you have defined the polygon with points using a coordinate system of a pane which is fixed at the root of the scene. *If you actually want the face to resize rather than just move, your approach will involve a slightly different application of the same concepts, particularly those of approach 2*.

There are two approaches I could think of to accomplish your goal of getting the nose to move with the rest of the face, I'll list my approaches in order of preference:

**Approach 1: A Pane specifically for the face.**
Rather than have each sub-piece of the smiley face define its position relative to the overall scene, have all of the pieces of the smiley face define their position relative to a pane which is just big enough to hold the outer circle of the smiley face. Then define the position of this pane relative to the pane for the root of the scene.

The reason I like this approach better is it has better encapsulation. For instance- if you later decide you want the whole smiley face to move around the screen, you can just define code to move the container pane rather than all the individual pieces. Similarly, adding new pieces only requires working in the coordinate system of that pane, so you don't have to consider making sure it moves appropriately within the overall scene.

Example code snippet for adding just the circle of the face to such a `smileyPane`. The polygon and the rest are left as an excercise :-)

```
    //This pane is the root of the scene, and stretches with the
    //stage. It will hold the smileyPane.
    Pane rootPane = new Pane();

    double smileyRadius = 50.0;

    //This pane is just big enough to hold the outer circle of
    //the smiley face. It holds all the individual pieces that 
    //make up the face.
    Pane smileyPane = new Pane();
    rootPane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            double smileyPaneStartX = (newValue.doubleValue()/2)-(smileyRadius); 
            smileyPane.setLayoutX(smileyPaneStartX);
        }
    });

    rootPane.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            double smileyPaneStartY = (newValue.doubleValue()/2)-(smileyRadius); 
            smileyPane.setLayoutY(smileyPaneStartY);
        }
    });
```

**Approach 2: Listeners to the outer pane dimensions which are used to recalculate the position of the nose.** Basically, you define some code to be run whenever the size of the outer Pane changes, so that you can recalculate the proper position of the nose/polygon.

```
  Polygon nose = new Polygon();
  nose.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
  nose.setFill(null);

  //Add initial nose position points
  nose.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{ 100.0, 90.0, 90.0, 120.0, 110.0, 120.0 });
  pane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        //The overall pane width changed. Recalculate the position of nose points
        //Actual position calculation left as exercise.
    }
  });

  //Similar thing needs to be done with height. Left as exercise.
```

---

I have left some pieces out, omitting the whole solution intentionally. This is clearly homework. This should be enough to get you started, but hopefully you'll learn something by filling in the pieces yourself!